# Mule: Convert XML to JSON with with some of the single element in XML as array in JSON

Tags: xml, json, xsd, mule

The contract with the client is to send `JSON` payload in rest web service call. In my `Mule` flow, I process `XML` and before doing web service call, convert it into `JSON` using

```
<json:xml-to-json-transformer>
```

which was working fine barring couple of issues. One of that is in `XSD` an element is defined with `maxOccurs="5"`, but most of the time this element occurs in `XML` only 1 time. So the problem is:

1. When an array has more than 1 entry, it is serialized correctly
2. When the array has only 1 entry, it is serialized not as an array, but as a single dictionary.

So, for this XML:

```
<team>
 <employee>
  <name>Joe</name>
  <surname>Bloggs</surname>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <name>Jane</name>
  <surname>Doe</surname>
 </employee>
</team>
```

JSON is:

```
{
team:{
 employee:[
  {
    name:'Joe',
    surname:'Bloggs'
  },
  {
    name:'Jane',
    surname:'Doe'
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

but for this `XML`

```
<team>
 <employee>
  <name>Joe</name>
  <surname>Bloggs</surname>
 </employee>
</team>
```

the `JSON` produced is:

```
{
  team:{
    employee:{
      name:'Joe',
      surname:'Bloggs'
    }
  }
}
```

The problem here is that client expects the value of `employee` to be an `array` (which it isn’t), violating the contract.

I read with the `custom-transformer` and `Object Mapper`, may be there is a way to specify which single element in XML should be forced to `array` in `JSON` or inject `XSD`. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no direct way of telling the JSON XML to JSON transformer to treat the element as an Array.

There are two options:

```
1. Implement a custom JSON transformer of Jackson and use the Force Array option. Please refer to the Jackson webpages for more detials.

2. If possible convert your XML to Java Object. 
The object will definitely would have defined the elements as an array or colelction.
Then convert the object to JSON which would be the final expected result of sinngle element as Array in JSON.


 <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer name="XmlToObject" jaxbContext-ref="JAXBContext" returnClass="java.lang.Object"/>
 <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using the `Force Array` option, how would it differentiate the element with single value which needs to convert to array versus which do not?

Comment: Even I got the same question,  but haven't looked into that option in-depth. Give it a try.  Option two is what I have executed and verfiied that it works.

Answer (score 1):

here is a different approach using dataweave.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    team: {
        employee: payload.team.*employee default []
    }
}
```

result is a employee attribute, wich always contains a list.

for `default []` to work you must specify the reader configuration like this:

```
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="06021518-b51d-4dbf-983d-b47ed5ffd0bc" doc:name="Transform Message">
    <dw:input-payload doc:sample="team.xml" mimeType="application/xml">
        <dw:reader-property name="nullValueOn" value="blank"/>
    </dw:input-payload>
    <dw:set-payload><!-- content of dataweave left out --></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this by adding an attribute to the element that needs to be treated as array and handling this by writing a custom Jackson transformer by extending the

> Blockquote
>    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer .

Hope this helps anyone trying to achieve this.